# How to think about system design questions methodically?

Tags: design, distributed-system

I'm working on my first big system design project at work for the first time in my career. In the past, while i've worked on large systems, I was always working with someone else, so I wasn't really responsible for design, I just understood the choices the made and pointed out potential upsides/downsides on specific things. Here, my manager basically gave me a vague problem and asked me to come up with a full system design.

Now, the problem isn't particularly "hard", it's actually a fairly common problem, but every design has it's own idiosyncrasies, which in my case I need to work around. Furthermore, even though at a high level the design I've come up with makes sense, I immediately start doubting whether it will work based on smaller details.

For example, I think to myself "Okay, if I ingest these raw events into a time series store, we should be able to do X and Y" "Oh no, if the time series query language doesn't support this kind of function, then we won't be able to do Z". Or "I want data in this structure, but the streaming tools we have won't easily support a transform like this in the pipeline itself. Does this mean we batch process after storage?"

Basically, I'm finding it difficult to design a full e2e system myself without getting bogged down or running into issues of "if this detail is wrong, the system won't work". I'm wondering how do more experienced people think of system design problems without getting bogged down by the details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Don't expect a precise system design to emerge from a vague problem description.**  The problem description *must be specific* to produce a high-quality solution.  Ask better questions, get better answers.

**Iterative design** exists to *solve vague, non-specific problems.*  It consists of building small, rapid prototypes (and sometimes creating small, rapid paper prototypes), showing the prototype to your stakeholders, getting feedback, and refining the prototype until the design satisfies the stakeholders' expectations, whatever those are.  At that point, the prototype embodies the design.

Don't try to be clairvoyant; you cannot anticipate every possible problem permutation.  Let the stakeholders tell you which system characteristics are most important to them, and tailor your design to those expectations.

If you're referring to overall *system design,* I have found that my expectations have been served well by a few general design principles.  Here are a few:

1. Break large problems into smaller, more easily digestible ones that can be handled by individual classes or methods.
2. Group "like" code together.  Write your software in layers.  This is called "Separation of Concerns," you can read up on it.
3. Leverage preexisting architectural solutions like MVVM.
4. Refactor mercilessly to keep your code clean, simple and easy to understand.
5. Understand your problem scope.  Large problems require more sophisticated architecture.

Naturally, the more experience you have writing code, the better this process works.

Comment: I would add "Aggressive test automation" to list of design principles. Can't refactor mercilessly with no tests.

Comment: Iterative design: yes, definitely. Write your software in layers: **definitely no**. MVVM: again, **definitely no**. These are the most common and most serious design errors in applications. Tearing objects apart by technology instead of localizing all related concepts in a cohesive unit. Technology is a detail, it shouldn't guide the design unless specific requirements demand it.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam: Neither MVVM nor software layers are *technologies,*  nor is their purpose to separate technologies.  They are conceptual localizations, just as you described.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Most common layers are: presentation, business, persistence. That is not a business-related separation. Business-related would be "Money", "Profile", "CashTransfer", "Account", etc. If something is not business-related, it's technical. You are localizing specific technologies instead of business-related knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Basically "fuggedaboutit!"

Any system design you do will have flaws, these will be fixed/remediated as the system evolves.

The main thing is to create a design which addresses the fundamental problems. Scale or Flexibility or Multi tenants or whatever the main problem experienced currently or by you competitors are.

You are never going to hit 100% on the first try, its better to get something out, without a major flaw, realise your design goals, and then iterate than try to design the perfect system from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

*"I immediately start doubting whether it will work based on smaller details."*

Unfortunately, many plans in software do fail due to small details.

If there is a particular grey area in your mind where you are aware that the details become fuzzy, then a good start is to focus on learning more details in that area. Investigate potential failure points at the very outset of the project.

I would also suggest sticking as much as possible to simpler approaches and tested technologies, if you know them already. Don't innovate everything at once, if you're already feeling like the task is heavy. You say the problems in your project are "common" ones - so must the solutions also be common and well-known.

I also assume you are working in a larger firm with other staff with at least as much experience as you have? Consult their opinions. Run your plans past them. If there are multiple special technologies in your solution, ask the experts on each.